# How do I declare a native interface with type variables in Frege?

Tags: java, generics, interface, frege, type-variables

I'd like to natively declare a java interface in Frege that has a generic type. For example let's take an ObservableList from JavaFX.

Leaving out the generic type E, it works to define

```
data ObservableList = mutable native javafx.collections.ObservableList where
```

but when I try

```
data ObservableList e = mutable native javafx.collections.ObservableList where
     native addAll  ::  ObservableList e -> MutableIO (JArray e) -> IO Bool
```

see the full example [here](https://github.com/Dierk/frepl-gui/blob/master/preFregeFX/src/main/frege/fregefx/javafx/collections/ObservableList.fr)

I get

```
kind error, type constructor `ObservableList` has kind ?->generic, expected was *
```

What is the advised way of handling this?

Comment: Please give a minimal complete definition that exhibits the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting, since it works for me out of the box:

```
ingo@freguntu:~/Frege/frege$ java -jar ../eclipse-plugin/lib/fregec.jar -version
3.23.247-gd535935
runtime 0.064 wallclock seconds.
ingo@freguntu:~/Frege/frege$ cat frege/StackOverflow.fr 
package StackOverflow where

data ObservableList e = mutable native javafx.collections.ObservableList where
  native addAll  ::  ObservableList e -> MutableIO (JArray e) -> IO Bool

ingo@freguntu:~/Frege/frege$ java -jar ../eclipse-plugin/lib/fregec.jar -d /tmp frege/StackOverflow.fr 
calling: javac -cp ../eclipse-plugin/lib/fregec.jar:/tmp -d /tmp -sourcepath . -encoding UTF-8 /tmp/StackOverflow.java 
Note: /tmp/StackOverflow.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
runtime 1.897 wallclock seconds.
ingo@freguntu:~/Frege/frege$
```

To be sure, the java compiler complains about the un-generic code that Frege emits, but there is no point in typechecking it again, only weaker :)

Please try the fregec that comes with the last eclipse plugin, it should work.

Also, when in eclipse, make sure you are not fooled by error markers not going away. For example, when you save, the errors become sticky and won't go away without recompilation.

Comment: ok, thanks. The point was really not in the code at all but in the handling of properly recompiling everything after the code change and reading the error messages that come from _users_ of this type, which have not yet been updated to reflect the type change.
*For other readers of this issue*: just do the "normal" thing in type declarations with classes, interfaces, generics, and the likes and it will work :-) My initial question was misleading.